# How to setup an offset function so it will take values from table horizontally and will go 2 rows down every 6 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to automate prices on my parents online shop and I've got pretty messy data to work with. I converted `csv` file with prices from site to `xlsx` and pasted there tables from the database.

I've linked a screenshot of the column where I must put all prices and one of the tables (I did something there as you can see but it only works for 6 rows and after I switch manually to X$6 it crashes *it doesn't include going 2 rows down in the table every 6 cells*)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/73DHp.png]

Address of the first cell with price from table is Y4 and Y5 merged (idk why X$4 worked but Y$4 didn't).

The formula shouldn't be affected by the place where it's used!

Comment: May be `=OFFSET($X$3;INT((ROW()+4)/6)*2-1;MOD(ROW()-2;6))`?

Comment: Works only well with the first product, I would need a function that's independent from the place I use it.

Comment: In this case IMHO it's worth considering writing a macro that will do all the work independent from the place. Or add `-ROW(<start cell>)` to the formula as a correction. Or run the formula each time starting from the second row, and then copy the result to the desired location in the resulting table.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please try to enter the formula in D2

`=OFFSET(Y$4,2*(TRUNC((ROW()-2)/6)),MOD(ROW()-2,6))`

Comment: The formula  i need can't be affected by the place where it's used :((

Comment: It's nice one ,, & working but Rows needs to be adjusted if Location changes like data is in A1:F2 ( 1,to 6 in Row 1 and 7 to 12 in Row 2),,, and formula in cell      H1 `=OFFSET(A$1,(TRUNC((ROW()-1)/8)),MOD(ROW()-1,8))`